# hook_menu question

Tags: routes

What is `"access content"` used as access argument in the following code? I don't see it in Drupal permissions.

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items['example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example Page',
    'page callback' => 'example_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That permission comes from the node module ([`node_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_permission/7)). Definition is:

```
'access content' => array(
  'title' => t('View published content'),
),
```

So in the permissions UI you'll be looking for "View published content".